# MacPorts for Python on Leopard

Tags: python, django, osx-leopard, macports

I haven't found any concrete language on the terminal commands for installing python 3.1 on Leopard using MacPorts. I already have 2.5.1 on Leopard by way of Apple. I don't want to mess with this version & I think having the newer version of Python running from my opt/local file would be better. Also SQL3 comes packed with the standard Python version on Leopard. Do I need to download SQL3 again via MacPorts in order for it to work with Python 3.1? thanks.

Comment: You've tagged this question with `django`, but note that Django is currently *not* compatible with Python 3.x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I haven't found any concrete language on the terminal commands for installing python 3.1 on Leopard using MacPorts.

`sudo port install python31` will install Python 3.1 (into `/opt/local`). In general, `port install <portname>` will install a port. You can find ports using `port search <string>` or [search online](http://www.macports.org/ports.php).

> I already have 2.5.1 on Leopard by way of Apple. I don't want to mess with this version & I think having the newer version of Python running from my opt/local file would be better.

MacPorts will install everything under `/opt/local`, and won't touch your Apple-supplied installs.

> Do I need to download SQL3 again via MacPorts in order for it to work with Python 3.1?

MacPorts will install the dependencies you need. `python31` depends on `sqlite3`, so SQLite 3 will automatically be downloaded and installed (under `/opt/local` -- Apple's version won't be touched).

Comment: Mipadi & Daniel thanks. This really does help me out a lot. Take care.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative way to install all Python flavors wherever you want:

```
$ cd <wherever>
$ svn http://svn.plone.org/svn/collective/buildout/python
$ cd python
$ python2.6 bootstrap.py
$ bin/buildout
```

It uses the system shipped Python to bootstrap the process. You'll also need Subversion installed. Make sure to edit the buildout.cfg file to add/remove versions you don't need.

It also installs PIL, readline, setuptools, virtualenv and a few more goodies, it's worth a try.